# Changes of one user does not appear in Gerrit

Tags: git, merge, gerrit

Together with my co-worker we're collaborating on some project, using Gerrit (and git, of course). We have both Gerrit and git properly configured (user names, user e-mails, SSH keys etc.) and everything works perfectly, except for the fact, that my colleague's changes doesn't appear in Gerrit.

Everything is OK in git layer. All changes are correctly merged and whenever he pushes his changes to Gerrit and then I pull all the changes, everything is also merged in my local repository. No code loss happens and it never happened before. The only obstacle, is that we can't see his changes (all is fine with my changes).

We're both Gerrit admins and we're added to group of owners of this project. I think, we checked everything, we could check. I think, I'm slowly running out of ideas. What can be causing such strange behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

That means your colleague is not submitting for reviews

```
git push HEAD:refs/for/master
```

He is rather doing direct push

```
git push master
```

So this has not gone thru gerrit, therefore you don't see.

Comment: Thanks (+1) for an attempt to solve this. I'll double check this on Monday. Unfortunately, I'm 99,9% sure, that this is not a case. I'm pretty sure, he **is** pushing changes with refs. I think, we even both have this added to repo's git configuration.

Comment: if he is pushing with ref/for/branchname ; after push you get a screen URL on screen.